# consult in mariadb, get the last message of each user

Tags: mysql, group-by, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group, groupwise-maximum

I am doing a chat and I need to make a query to my database in which I bring the last message that a user received from each person with whom he wrote, the query should be based on the date, the last message according to the date

the table would be the following

```
id   id_destination   message   sender     date
1          1123          hi      1133    18/06/2019
2          1123          bye     1133    17/06/2019
3          1123          ok      1144    18/06/2019
4          1123          hi      1144    17/06/2019
```

I need that once executed the query will show me in the following way:

```
id   id_destination   message   sender     date
1          1123          hi      1133    18/06/2019
3          1123          ok      1144    18/06/2019
```

Comment: I am reverting your latest edit. We very much prefer text to images in questions.

Answer (score 0):

try by using dense_rank()

```
slect * from 
(select *,dense_rank()over(partition by id_destination order by date desc) rn
from table
) a where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the message with the highest id for each destination and sender, using this subquery.

```
                          SELECT MAX(id) id
                            FROM messages
                        GROUP BY id_destination, sender
```

Then use it to select messages, like this: (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9W7YTSN8Dq7TuRYnL1jmXE/0)

```
   SELECT *
     FROM messages
    WHERE id IN (
                          SELECT MAX(id) id
                            FROM messages
                        GROUP BY id_destination, sender
                )
```

You may append `AND sender = something` or any other filter to this.

This assumes each new message gets an autoincrementing ID value, so later messages have higher ID values than earlier ones.

Using the dates is a little trickier, and a lot slower. (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6MKc7At6MKPm98eUEPKMYz/0) .  It also has a potential ambiguity, if multiple messages occur on the latest date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages m
JOIN (
                      SELECT MAX(date) date, id_destination, sender
                        FROM messages
                    GROUP BY id_destination, sender
     ) x ON m.date=x.date 
        AND m.id_destination = x.id_destination
        AND m.sender = x.sender
```